# flutter pub run build_runner stuck

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm having issue running the

```
flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
```

The command does not go in error, but it's stuck on the first file:

```
WARNING] No actions completed for 15.0s, waiting on:
  - auto_route_generator:autoRouteGenerator on lib/ui/shared/ui_helpers.dart
  - auto_route_generator:autoRouteGenerator on lib/ui/views/settings/settings_datamodel.dart
  - auto_route_generator:autoRouteGenerator on lib/ui/views/settings/settings.dart
  - auto_route_generator:autoRouteGenerator on lib/ui/views/review_invitation/review_invitation_datamodel.dart
  - auto_route_generator:autoRouteGenerator on lib/ui/views/review_invitation/review_invitation.dart
  .. and 9 more

[INFO] 1m 17s elapsed, 1/15 actions completed.
```

The following is my pubspec:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # see below for explanation
  stacked_services:
  auto_route:
  stacked: ^1.7.6
  stacked_hooks: 0.1.1+3
  flutter_hooks:
  get_it:
  injectable:
  validators: ^2.0.0 

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  build_runner:
  auto_route_generator:
  injectable_generator:
```

While this is the class for my router.dart

```
import 'package:auto_route/auto_route_annotations.dart';
import 'package:myapp/ui/views/StartupView.dart';

@MaterialAutoRouter(
  routes: <AutoRoute>[
    MaterialRoute(page: StartupView, initial: true),
  ],
)
class $Router {}
```

Any advices?

Comment: 1: `flutter clean` 2: `flutter doctor -v` 3. try for build again

Comment: it's still stuck. I don't know why it doesn't work

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A `flutter pub upgrade` solved my issue.

Answer (score 3):

**method-1:** if after **upgrade flutter** this issue happened try run:

`flutter packages upgrade`
then `flutter pub run build_runner build`

---

**method-2:** this solves it for me:

1- `flutter clean`

2- delete all *.g.dart if exist

3- go on dev channel: `flutter channel dev`

4- upgrade: `flutter upgrade --force`

5- `flutter pub get`

6- try to build: `flutter pub run build_runner build`

7- back on stable or master channel: `flutter channel stable` (`flutter channel master`)

8- upgrade: `flutter upgrade --force`

---

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that your project name doesn't contain '%20' characters. This causes any build methods, like `flutter packages pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs` and `flutter pub run build_runner clean` to fail.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is stuck with the same issue try upgrading flutter from v1.20.1 to v1.20.2